# CSS - How can I divide a list <li> in 3 columns using li:nth-child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

There are 6 elements and I want them to be something like that:

```
 - First     - Third     - Fifth
 - Second    - Fourth    - Sixth
```

I tried something like this:

```
li:nth-child(6n+1) {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

li:nth-child(2n+3) {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: You can use `display: grid` and `grid-layout` for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Not sure how can I apply this, I'm really a begginer, but think its a way. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS grid like below:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  list-style: none;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! although it didn't turn out the way I wanted, it worked. But I got it another way as well: 
li:nth-child(2n+0) {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
}
li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    float: right;
    width: 33.3%;

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example of that layout using CSS Grid; as @NickG mentioned, it's worth reading up on [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), as it's a really useful concept to learn.

Below, I've assigned each div a `grid-area` name, and used that to reference the layout you described with `grid-template-areas`.

```css
.container {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 8px 8px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one three five"
    "two four six";
}

.container * {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: orange;
}

.one { grid-area: one; }

.two { grid-area: two; }

.three { grid-area: three; }

.four { grid-area: four; }

.five { grid-area: five; }

.six { grid-area: six; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
  <div class="five">5</div>
  <div class="six">6</div>
</div>
```